# ScriptTimeoutError: Timed out - From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular()

Tags: protractor

I am trying to run basic end to end tests written using protractor. I always get this error.

> ScriptTimeoutError: Timed out

I checked this link https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md and increased the default timeout, but still I get the same error. I am not able to figure out from where this error pops out. The browser loads the base Url, later it will not perform any action as mentioned in the test. The test is very simple , open the browser and click on the menu and verify if the URL is matched.

- Node Version: v7.5.0
- Protractor Version: 5.1.2
- Angular Version: 2.4.10
- Browser(s): firefox
- Operating System and Version ubuntu
- typescript: 2.2.2

[image]
Config file

```
 exports.config = {
      framework: 'jasmine2',    
      seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
      specs: ['test/e2e/menu.js'],
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'firefox', 
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8100/#/',
    //allScriptsTimeout: 360000, 
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
       showColors: true,
      // defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000
     },
    //useAllAngular2AppRoots:true,

//menu.js
describe('menu check', function () {
   beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/');
      browser.waitForAngular();
     // browser.driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60000);
   });

    it('Should route to the operationalView page from menu', function () {
       element(by.css('[href="#/operationalView"]')).click();
       expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('http://localhost:8100/#/operationalView');
    });

    it('Should route to the worldlview page from menu', function () {
        element(by.css('[href="#/worldView"]')).click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('http://localhost:8100/#/worldView');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had this issue once, which I resolved using

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization=true
```

before the `beforeEach()` method in your Protractor spec files. This makes Protractor not wait for Angular promises, such as those from `$http` or `$timeout` to resolve. You can try this in your script.

Edit : As of today, 08/16/19, this solution has been deprecated. Use `waitForAngularEnabled` to be `false` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It worked finally.. I was cracking my head for this issue..Thanks