# Cucumber - Unable to execute the step definition file

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber

I am having angular 2 application. I have written basic cucumber tests. I have added feature and steps definiton file.I dont understand why it is not able to read the step definition file even though i have clearly defined it. When I try to execute the cucumber tests, I get this error message:

[image]

> versions : protractor - 5.1.2 , node -7.5,npm -4.1.2, cucumber -2.3.1,
>   protractor-cucumber-framewrok - 3.1.2

Here is the sample code:

```js
//cucumber.conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  directConnect: true,
  specs: ['test/e2e/cucumber/sample.feature'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        //"--headless",
        "--disable-gpu",
        '--disable-extensions',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-web-security'
      ],
    },

  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/dashboard/#/',
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,


  // cucumber command line options
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['test/e2e/cucumber/menu.steps.js'],
    tags: [],
    strict: true,
    format: ["pretty"],
    dryRun: false,
    compiler: []
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
  },

  resultJsonOutputFile: './test/e2e/results.json'
}

/**
//test/e2e/cucumber/sample.feature
Feature: The Dashboard has 2 views, Main view and Status view

Scenario: I want to have 2 tabs with Displayed text "Main View"
and "Status View"
on the homepage

Given I go to Dashboard homepage
When I click on the Main view
Then the main view page is displayed
When I click on the Status view
Then the status view page is displayed

*/

//test/e2e/cucumber/menu.steps.js
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
module.exports = function() {
    this.Given(/^I go to Dashboard homepage$/, {
      timeout: 100 * 1000
    }, function() {
      return browser.get('http://localhost:8080/dashboard/#/');
      // browser.waitForAngular();
    });

    this.When(/^I click on the Main view$/, {
      timeout: 100 * 1000
    }, function() {
      element(by.css('[href="#/mainView"]')).click();
    });

    this.Then(/^the main view page is displayed$/, function() {
          return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            console.log("URL= " + url);
          });

          this.When(/^I click on the Status view$/, {
            timeout: 100 * 1000
          }, function() {
            element(by.css('[href="#/statusView"]')).click();
          });

          this.Then(/^the status view page is displayed$/, function() {
            return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
              console.log("URL= " + url);
            });
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CucumberJS 2 you need to use a different way of writing your steps, see [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md) for more info.

**Example:**

```js
// features/step_definitions/file_steps.js
var {
  defineSupportCode
} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function({Given}) {

  Given(/^I need to rewrite my steps$/, function() {
    return Promise.resolve('pending');
  });
  
});
```

Secondly be aware of the fact that this will not work, you are placing the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` on top of a file. When the file is read by protractor the browser is not started yet, so it will fail hard.

If you need to test a non-angular page place the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in the config file in the `onPrepare()`.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah the cucumber version was different. Now i downgraded to 1.3.3 and it worked. I have added `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` to avoid timeout issue.This makes Protractor not wait for Angular promises, such as those from $http or $timeout to resolve. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672875/scripttimeouterror-timed-out-from-task-protractor-waitforangular)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience feature files are very sensitive to formatting. Much like a yml file, I've had steps not run because of tabs and spaces, so I would also check for that too.